# Windows --> Assembly folder typical size: aka GAC

Tags: cache, assembly

I am a .net developer on a Win 7 RC1 (x64) machine and I happened to notice that my GAC(Global Assembly Cache) folder is 1.2 GBs in size(1700 files).

This got me wondering what the "normal" size is and what implications having one this large may have beyond the obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that the GAC can store multiple versions of the same assembly (to avoid ".DLL Hell", that is, a reference can link to a specific version to avoid version incompatibilities). My GAC on Windows XP SP3 is 939Mb, spread across 1500+ files. Your numbers seem pretty normal to me.